Trouble Integrating Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) Library into an Existing iOS Framework
Trouble Integrating Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) Library into an Existing iOS Framework
Hi all,
I'm currently developing a Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) library, which I need to package as a framework for integration into another iOS framework, not directly into an iOS app. While exporting the KMP library as a framework for iOS app integration works smoothly (I'm using the embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode Gradle task), I'm facing issues when trying to incorporate this KMP framework into another iOS framework.
The Problem:
The integration fails with errors indicating that the KMP framework isn't recognized or compatible within the target iOS framework. Specifically, the error suggests that the framework cannot be found, even though it's built and available.
I am not using CocoaPods for managing dependencies—I'm directly embedding the framework. The integration into an iOS app itself is working fine, but the issue arises when trying to link the KMP framework inside another iOS framework.
What I've Tried:

The KMP framework works when integrated directly into an iOS app.
I’ve verified that the framework is being built and is available, but it’s not recognized when added to another framework.
I’m embedding it via the Xcode settings and have ensured the linking and embedding steps are done correctly.

My Questions:

Has anyone successfully integrated a KMP framework into an existing iOS framework? If so, are there any additional steps or configurations required to make the KMP framework compatible with another iOS framework?
Could this be an issue related to framework search paths or other Xcode settings that I might be overlooking?
Are there any troubleshooting techniques or known best practices when embedding KMP frameworks into iOS frameworks (rather than directly into apps)?

I appreciate any insights or guidance on this topic!
Thanks in advance! 
edit:
here's the build.gradle.kts, it is so basic
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = false // I tired with both true and false here
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            //put your multiplatform dependencies here
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mobilez.regularapplication"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


Post your build.gradle file so we can help troubleshoot

@RobertJamison Yes, sir! Please find the file you requested.
By the way, I added it like any regular framework in Xcode.

I've done it successfully many times.
The issue is that your library is not automatically included in the dependencies of your app, even though they're in the same directory.
If I understand correctly, you have a project that includes a folder called shared with your app files, and a folder next to it named after your library (e.g. libraryFolder).  If so, this is how you'd add the library as a reference in your build.gradle file:
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(project(":libraryFolder"))
        }

